# "Enlightened" Badge wrongly awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, accepted-answer

I just got the Enlightened badge for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615551/function-with-infinitely-many-right-inverses/1615552#1615552), and I don't understand why. The description of the badge is:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more.

I was indeed the first to answer and I did get a score of 11, but my answer was not accepted, so I souldn't have gotten the badge. Could this be a bug, or is there something I don't get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the [reputation tab of the author of the currently accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154802/mathmo123?tab=reputation)

[image]

you can see that the answer was today first unaccepted (11:04:00), and later re-accepted (11:05:36).

It is very likely that in between your answer was accepted, causing the badge criteria to be met, and the badge awarded to you (11:05:12). Congratulations.

Your answer was however not accepted long enough to generate an entry in your reputation tab.

Comment: Isn't the reputation immediately given when an answer is accepted?

Comment: Yes, but it is also immediately taken away when an answer is unaccepted. If the unaccept comes soon enough after the accept, no entry in the reputation tab is generated.

Comment: Ok, that's probably what happened. I seemed weird to me because I didn't even know that an answer had been accepted. Thank you for the explanation.